# How to change Google Maps coordinates while clicking external link

Tags: javascript, google-maps, hyperlink, external

I normally don't work 'outside of the box' when working with the Google Maps API so I'm a bit of a novice and that's why I'm asking here. But for the project I'm working on now we're trying create a Store Locator that changes the google maps coordinates when an user clicks on a store name, which is a link just under our map div.

I was hoping if you people could help me out here because I couldn't find any answers by using Google.

Thanks!

Comment: you want to display multiple locationg on map

Comment: You can start with getting a global `map` variable which you can use on other parts of your code. Try some yourself and post some code, you'll get help.